# Salate el Isstikhara to answer personal questions (professional life)?

Tags: dua, work, life, istikharah

Salam,

Can Salat el isstikhara help me to understand and to answer questions related to my professional life ? For example, I do not find my place, I am 33 years old and still did not find the meaning of my life, what I want to do, which job is fiting me, what I can provide to siciety and be paid for my services.

I am reading about ikigai for example, well, It can be good to keep positive thinking and optimism, but I wonder if Isstikhara is meant to be for my situation.

Comment: We have a lots of questions on istikhara and none of the answers satisfies your need?

Comment: @Medi1Saif indeed good questions about istikhara, but almost all of them are about mariage

Comment: But the hadith of istikhara actually answers your inquiry and it should be mentioned in some of these.

Answer (score -2):

Assalamu alaikum, the solution for your situation is reading and learning Quran.
Allah subhanahu va ta'ala says: "I did not create the Jinns and the human beings except for the purpose that they should worship Me." Adh-Dhariyat(56)
Allah created us to worship only for Him. That is the meaning of our life. We should perform all salahs on time.

Comment: This actually does nothing to answer the question.